# Cannot Import Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-analytics

I have compiled the gradle file but I cannot import any Files related to Google Analytics in my project. In a new project it is working but not in this one. I don't know what's going wrong.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'


android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.whizkidzmedia.youhuu"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 40
        versionName "3.1"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            // shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            //shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-beta-3'
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:0.15.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each {
            task ->
                task.builtins {
                    remove javanano
                    java {
                    }
                }
                task.plugins {
                    grpc {
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '24.2.1'
    grpcVersion = '0.15.0'
}





repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.0'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/fortumo-in-app-android-sdk.jar')
    compile("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    }
    compile("io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    }
    compile("io.grpc:grpc-auth:${grpcVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    }
    compile("io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:${grpcVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    }
    // OAuth2 for Google API
    compile('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.3.0') {
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.6.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please do let me know how to solve this issue.This is the classpath in Project level gradle.

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

Answer (score 0):

Android IDE restart Fixed this